# managing color in xlsxwriter chart

Tags: excel, python-2.7, xlsxwriter

Excel 2016 / Python 2.7.6 / XlsxWriter 1.1.1

I'm writing code to select files, compile them into one .xlsx file, and plot them on 2 charts on their own sheets. Ideally, I would like to force series from the same tab to be the same color. Unfortunately, xlsxwriter doesn't recognize the color names from Excel 2016.

I'd prefer to use the color order that Excel chooses by default. One of the charts is fine (I'm not specifying the color, it's only one x & y axis, one series per tab). The other is less so. I'm plotting one series as a line against the left Y axis, I'm plotting one against the right Y axis and I want to match the color, and I am plotting a third series also against the right Y axis and I want to only use markers for that. There isn't a finite number of tabs, but typically there would be 5.

The default colors are blue, red, olive green, purple, aqua, and orange (I haven't gone beyond those). I tried creating a list of those colors, but it doesn't recognize olive green or aqua. Changing those to green and cyan is too harsh.

Is there a way to allow xlsxwriter to select the colors and then to get the color for that series and apply it to the next one? Is it best to find the Hex code for each color and use that instead?

```
colors = ['blue', 'red', 'Olive Green', 'purple', 'Aqua', 'orange', 'lime', 'magenta', 'navy',  'pink', 'cyan',
          'silver', 'brown'] #named colors to cycle through

series_to_delete = [] #for legend simplicity
series = len(files) 
j = 0


for df, tab in zip(dfs, tabs):
    if j > len(colors): #if you run out of colors, go back to the beginning
        j = 0
    color = colors[j] #choose a color
    df.to_excel(writer, tab) #write the df to a tab

    x_categories = "='" + tab + "'!$a$2:$a$5000"  #for the first plot
    y_values = "='" + tab + "'!$c$2:$c$5000" #y values used in both plots

    x2_categories = "='" + tab + "'!$b$2:$b$5000" #second plot, x axis

    y2_values = "='" + tab + "'!$d$2:$d$5000" #second plot, second y axis

    x3_categories = "='" + tab + "'!$e$2:$e$5000" #these are markers
    y3_values = "='" + tab + "'!$f$2:$f$5000" #this is the 3rd series on plot 2

    chart.add_series({'name': tab, 'categories': x_categories, 'values': y_values}) #plot 1, note no named color
    chart2.add_series({'name': tab, 'categories': x2_categories, 'values': y_values, 'line': {'color': color}}) #plot 2, against 1st y axis
    chart2.add_series({'name': tab, 'categories': x2_categories, 'values': y2_values, 'y2_axis': 1,
                   'line': {'color': color, 'transparency': 50}}) #plot 2, against 2nd y axis

    chart2.add_series({'categories': x3_categories, 'values': y3_values, 'line':   {'none': True},
                   'marker': {'type': 'automatic'}, 'y2_axis': 1,
                   'data_labels': {'value': True, 'category': True, 'separator': "\n"}}) #plot 2, against 2nd y axis

    j += 1
    series_to_delete.append(series) #this is so the legend isn't cluttered
    series_to_delete.append(series + 1) #with each series named 3X
    series += 2

chart2.set_legend({'delete_series': series_to_delete})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it best to find the Hex code for each color and use that instead?

Yes. There are only a limited number of [named colors in XlsxWriter](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/working_with_colors.html) and they only exist for backward compatibility reasons and for making examples a little clearer.

If you want your own color palette then you can work one out using a HTML color picker ([such as this one](https://www.w3schools.com/colors/colors_picker.asp)).

Note, your ranges such as `$a$2:$a$5000` are wrong. Excel uses uppercase column letters. A better approach is to avoid trying to construct these types of ranges manually and use the list syntax for categories and values instead, like this:

```
chart.add_series({'name': tab, 
                  'categories': [tab, 1, 0, 4999, 0], 
                  'values':     [tab, 1, 2, 4999, 2]})
```

See the docs on [add_series()](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/chart.html#chart-add-series) for an explanation of this list syntax.

Comment: That color picker is fantastic - much more helpful than the links I'd found prior to this!  The info on the series stuff is good. I could make my code more robust by programatically determining the indices I actually need to plot, which will be useful in the future. Excel DOES use capital letters for columns, but it also forces any lowercase letters to be capitals.